# how to use jquery Count plugin for label inside a repeater?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, label, repeater, countdown

I have label inside a repeater(DataBound control). Now i want to use count Down jquery plugin on it. Actually what i want to do here i have a date like "12/07/2012" I want to Calculate number of hours till now from that date. For it i have found CountDown Plugin which will update time using the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    @import "Countdown.countdown.css";
</style>
<%--Scripts Starts from here. --%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Countdown/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var longWayOff = new Date();
        //longWayOff.setDate(longWayOff.getDate() + 500);
        longWayOff.setDate(longWayOff.getDate());
        var liftoffTime = new Date();
        var startYear = new Date();
        startYear = new Date(startYear.getFullYear(), 1 - 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

        //liftoffTime.setDate(liftoffTime.getDate() + 72);
        liftoffTime.setDate(liftoffTime.getHours() + 72);
        // $('#noDays').countdown({ until: liftoffTime, format: 'HMS' });
        $('#noDays').countdown({ since: startYear, compact: true,
            format: 'HMS', description: ''
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<span id="noDays" class="countdown"></span>
</div>
```

Now i when i trying to use the same code for repeater its not working as its not able to find label's it.Then I take run time id using Firebug and apply the script for that id it works fine. My Question is How we can use count down Plugin for label inside a repeater.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like repeater are searchable in the DOM after the Document.Ready !
You could use the help of the live() function, to trigger you timer.

you could also try to see if the repeater is present at the time of the Document.ready :

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
  jQuery.contains(document.body, $('#Repeater'));
})
```

Comment: I am not getting what you want to say can you please elaborate what you want to say..

Comment: oK, I'll do my best: 1st you want to make sure that your reaper is present in your DOM tree. jQuery.contains(document.body, $('#Repeater')); gives you an opportunity to see just that (it returns a boolean, i.e: 'true' if the repeater is here). As soon as figured out, if your repeater element is present, or not, then we will try to see, what's the next step